# webservice container's

Tags: web-services

axis is a example of a webservice container. Can someone please name a few more ?

Comment: well how can i accept a answer that i dont feel comfortable with?

Answer (score 0):

[Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/windowsazure/) (if that's what you mean)

Answer (score 0):

[Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) is a good candidate.

Comment: what how can tomcat be a web-service container ? Isn't it a servlet container ?

Comment: True it is a servlet container, but you can deploy web services as well, see this link:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/

Comment: Sure I will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

jBoss is also used for similar purpose

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant SOAP based web service libraries/APIs;

Java:

- [JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net/)
- [GlassFish Metro](http://metro.java.net/) (based on JAX-WS)
- [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)

.NET:

- [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)